# I can't render reactdom

Tags: html, reactjs, npm

I am new to react but I have experience in `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `CSS`. I installed node and npm and using npm and I entered the following command on to my windows pc.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

That will install a command line utility called `create-react-app` and then created my react app by entering the following command:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Now I've setup everything I decided I try out a bit of react and edited app.js. I added in the following lines last (except the import one).

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const h1 = ( <h1>Hey there!</h1> );
ReactDOM.render(h1, document.getElementById("test") );
//the id "test" was assigned to a <h1> element in index.js
```

Now I saved it and ran the following commands:

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

Now came the error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Has anybody experienced the same error? 
If you have please can you tell me how to fix it?

PS: I did the code editing in visual studio code if that helps.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't match your code. What happened?

Comment: I know. I do not know why that happened because if i took the code i wrote out, it works and there is no error.

Comment: I know this is stupid and probably doesn't help, but check whether you have saved the file and restart the dev server

Comment: I definitely saved it and i just restarted the dev server and it still shows the same error.

Comment: Wait hold on you said you edited App.js?

Comment: You should be editing index.js instead

Comment: Oh ok. But the webserver says to edit app.js instead? edit: now i moved the code but the expected result doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have ReactDOM in your index.js
there should be only one RenderDOM in your app and that is your index.js. this  is
because of create-react-app webpack config it will only read ReactDOM from index.js.

Change App.js to :

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    );
};

export default App;
```

and Change Index.js to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

Comment: Thanks @VJ Solanki!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one if you dont want App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
   return (<h1>HELO WORLD</h1>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('test'));
```